# Entity - Desativar Lazy Loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou no inicio do desenvolvimento de projeto. Este projeto terá uma base de dados grande. É aconselhável manter o lazy load ativado? Fico preocupado de acarretar em perda de performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> É aconselhável manter o lazy load ativado?

Sim. Não está correto associar a carga preguiçosa necessariamente com perda de performance.

A carga preguiçosa existe para tornar o desenvolvimento ágil e sem complicações. Você não precisa usá-la todo o tempo. Ela pode causar sim perdas de performance em telas com exibição de muitos registros que tenham registros dependentes de cardinalidade N, e ainda assim esse problema pode ser tratado pontualmente em código.

Se quiser antecipar a carga, use [`Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) para avisar ao Entity Framework para realizar a consulta usando `JOINS`.

Exemplo:

```
var registro = db.Registros.Include(r => r.RegistrosDependentes).ToList();
```

A query gerada terá:

```
SELECT R1.COLUNA1, R1.COLUNA2, ...
FROM REGISTROS R1
INNER JOIN REGISTROSDEPENDENTES R2 ON R1.REGISTROID = R2.REGISTROID
```

Comment: Por exemplo, estou com lazy load ativado. Vou na base de dados e tenho certeza que vou usar os dados de um relacionamento. Neste caso seria melhor fazer um include nesta consulta? Ou seja, com o include neste cenário minha performance seria maior?

Comment: Sim, com certeza. Esta é a ideia. Quando não tem essa certeza, a carga preguiçosa é melhor.

Answer (score 2):

A seguir estão as vantagens de o Lazy Loading

Minimiza o tempo de inicialização do aplicativo.

Aplicação consome menos memória por causa de carregamento on-demand.

Execução de banco de dados SQL desnecessário é evitado.

A única desvantagem é que o código torna-se complicadado recisamos verificar se o loading é necessária ou não,sendo assim há uma diminuição no desempenho.

Mas as vantagens são muito mais do que as desvantagens.

O oposto do  `lazy loading` é `eager loading` . Assim, em `eager loading` os objetos são carregados na memorias assim que os objetos são criados

Ao meu ver, não há certo ou errado, você tem que decidir se prefere carregar em run time ou loading times.

leia mais em: (inglês) :[Is Lazy Loading really bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155363/is-lazy-loading-really-bad)

[Good or bad practice? Initializing objects in getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774008/good-or-bad-practice-initializing-objects-in-getter)