# Entity Framework, code First, Consulta no banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Boa noite, tenho duas classes a qual uma é um atributo da outra, Cliente tem Anamnese , quando faço a busca no banco de dados o retorno é o cliente certinho, porem o campo Anamnese é null, e quero recuperar essas informações.

Classe Cliente

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public Anamnese Anamnese { get; set; }
```

Classe Anamnese

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

meu banco esta ok, cliente tem os dados dele e uma chave estrangeira de anamnese e consigo salvar normalmente um novo cliente ja com seu anamnese.

Metodo usado para cadastro de nova anamnese

```
public static void CadastrarAnamnese(Cliente clienteEntrada, Anamnese anamnese) {
        try
        {
            using (ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
            {
                Cliente cliente = ctx.Clientes.Find(clienteEntrada.Id);
                cliente.Anamnese = anamnese;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Como está recuperando, utilizou o include!?

Comment: Não, tentei isso agora mais não consegui usar, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: `var cliente = ctx.Clientes.Where(c => c.Id == id).Include(c => c.Anamnese).FirstOrDefault();          

                             Anamnese teste = cliente.Anamnese;`

com essas duas linhas consegui obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer usar o [*Lazy Loading*](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) é só mudar as classes assim:

**Classe Cliente**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Anamnese Anamnese { get; set; }
```

**Classe Anamnese**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Clientes{ get; set; }
```

Dessa forma, mantendo a consulta do jeito que você já está fazendo, irá trazer os dados de `Anamnese` usando [Lazy Loading](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx), de forma automática.

**Ou...**

como já comentaram, você pode usar o `include` caso não queira mesmo fazer uso o Lazy Loading, altere a consulta assim:

```
Cliente cliente = ctx.Clientes.Include(c => c.Anamnese).Find(clienteEntrada.Id);
```

Aqui no SOpt mesmo tem algumas boas respostas sobre o *Lazy Loading* caso queira entender melhor antes de usa-lo indiscriminadamente:

1. [Como funciona o Lazy Load Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20646/35358)
2. [Entity - Desativar Lazy Loading?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109552/35358)